# Type or namespace not found. Visual Studio suddenly demands global prefix on using statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, resharper, using

It happened to me before and I never know why it happens.

Suppose you have a simple C# class with some ***using*** statements *inside(!)* the namespace definition. It worked flawlessly for hours. Now I worked on a completely different project and  all of a sudden the former project won't compile anymore claiming a part of the namespace cannot be found anymore. R# then suggests to fix this by using **global::...**

***The type or namespace name 'Internet' does not exist in the namespace 'Cmp.Internet.Portal.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)***

so

```
using Cmp.Internet.Portal.Web.Common;
```

becomes

```
using global::Cmp.Internet.Portal.Web.Common;
```

I do understand what it means but I'm puzzled about why it happens.
And it should not even be necessary.

**An example to make it more obvious...**

Let's assume I have 3 projects.

- Project.Core
- Project.One (references Project.Core)
- and Project.Two (references Project.Core)

Now *Project.One* can have using statements inside its namespace without using the global prefix. *Project.Two* cannot. Why? ...

Comment: You'll have named something the same as a .net namespace or class.

Comment: Taking a wild guess here but there isn't a one to one correspondence between name spaces and assemblies in your code?

Comment: In my recent example it suddenly affected 9 using statements at once. All of them are my ones (e.g. no System.* or Microsoft.*). They are spread within 5 different assemblies. I didn't create any new classes recently.. I'm pretty sure of that.

Comment: No it's not a 1:1 relationship. As we are in the middle of a refactoring process there are classes with "old" namespaces in "new" assemblies. But I'm not aware of any rule that one assembly can only use one namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem occurred because different assemblies provided the same namespaces. It happened because we were in the middle of a refactoring and classes were moved between assemblies.

Once every namespace was provided by only one assembly the global:: prefix became superfluous.